# How to find a table inside and out using one line of code?

Tags: jquery, find, closest

I have a filter inside a table. I also have a filter outside the table, and a div surrounding the table.

What I want is to get the table name when the filter is clicked on. I have given the filter a class and I use a click event. The problem is that I want both filters to work on the table.

Right I know how to search for the table from the filter outside(the filter is in an input). So when my click event fires I can get the table name like this

```
var tablename = $(this).parent().find('table').attr('id');
```

and I know how to find the table name from inside the filter inside the table with the following line

```
var tablename=$(this).closest('table').attr('id');
```

The trouble is instead of using two different lines of code to find the table name, I would like to find one line of code that can do both of the above.

Is there such code to do this?
Or do I need to run both lines see which one is undefined.

Comment: Please post your HTML

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one table on the page then you can just use `$('table')` or something like `$('table.table-with-filters')`.

If there are many tables with filters, I see few options:

1) Try to find the table in both ways and use non-empty result (similar to what you suggested in the question)

2) Mark the filter with some class like `.inner-filter` and `.outer-filter`, then use this class inside the filter handler to decide how to search for a table

3) Assign the table an id like `#data-table-1` and configure your filters with the id of related table, then just do `$('#data-table-1')` to find it